# How to delete specific HTTP authentication credentials from Safari (for Windows)?

Tags: windows, safari, authentication

I use Safari on a Windows XP machine at work. To access the corporate intranet website, Safari asks me the first time to enter my credentials, using a default HTTP(?) authentication dialog box. On subsequent visits, Safari logs me in automatically.

However, now that I have changed my password, Safari no longer displays the page, keeps trying to load it with the old password, and eventually displays an authentication error page.

Is there any way to clear the stored credentials **for that specific website only**? I can of course reset Safari entirely, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: An answer to this would be nice, I get this in Firefox too and its quite bothersome. The only way I've found so far requires me to have access to the sites code to delete the authentication server-side and force re-auth  :(

Comment: By that I mean, there is no way at all to "Log out" once logged in normally without a browser reset.

Comment: you can use Roboform password manager for safari.. but currently its not supported . End of 2009 . They are going to support safari.

Comment: Safari (and other browsers) caches credentials during your session. Have you tried a relaunch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Manage Your Passwords**

Step 1:
      Go to the 'AutoFill' section in the Safari Preferences window.

Step 2:
      Click on the 'Edit' button to the right of where it says 'User Names and Passwords.' This will bring up a window displaying all of the passwords and usernames that you have authorized Safari to save.

Step 3:
      Click on a password listing and push the 'Remove' button in order to delete the password from Safari's memory.

Step 4:
      Choose 'Remove All' in order to delete all of the saved passwords.

Step 5:
      Manage your passwords as you see fit.

Source : http://www.answerbag.com/articles/How-to-Manage-Passwords-With-Safari/f6de5c02-c6e6-0f2c-5f27-197a996ebced

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted, as this is probably the best workaround. The intranet site is not listed in the dialog box, but choosing 'Remove All' does clear the stored credentials for it. Too bad it also clears the other stored passwords though.

Comment: This doesn't seem too good since removing credentials from Safari's AutoFill password will delete them from Keychain as well. I use keychain exactly to *store* the credentials in first place. Notice the question was about clearin "credentials for that specific website only".

Comment: This should not be the correct answer, since it seems basic auth passwords are not saved here

Answer (score 15):

If you are on **Mac OS X** and you are wondering how to remove a basic-authentication credential from a website, you won't find the password in Safari preferences.  The answer is in the **Keychain Access App**.  Open it up (it's in Utilities) and then go to the **Passwords Category** (the categories are on the left, at the bottom - you don't need to be doing anything with your keychains here). Search for the name you want to get rid of (it will be something like "your.internetserver.com (john.doe)", select it, right click, and then delete it.

Comment: This is the correct way to remove a cached basic authentication password.  I was suffering from inconsistent behavior and there were two differing passwords in my keychain and Safari was just picking one as far as I can tell :(

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to make Safari prompt for credentials again by explicitly specifying wrong credentials:

```
http://foo:bar@yourintranetserver/
```

This assuming your actual user and password aren't actually "foo" and "bar".

You can save it as bookmark calling it "reset intranet credentials".

Comment: Safari 8 does not like that: doesn't recognise addresses that begin with "foo:" ---- IDIOTS

Comment: it does work when fooling Safari with: `http://http:foo:bar@yourintranetserver/`

Comment: Right, filed a radar bug.

Comment: This no longer reliably works.. Use the revised method above (which I wrote having seen that this doesn't work)

Answer (score 3):

This reminds me that I can temporary change my auth credential in Chrome by using Incognito mode (private browsing). -- FYI

Comment: Duh, great tip!